# Django ORM - Get distinct objects based on string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My object has this layout on mariaDB (no postgres here):

```
+------+------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|  id  |           created            | message  |  from   |                  guest_id                  |
+------+------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| '45' | '2021-03-02 21:32:56.756966' | 'Hello ' | 'host'  | 'e5b15b726e1224ca1d70ad9cf6a6e2a485de5478' |
| '46' | '2021-03-02 23:32:56.756966' | 'bye'    | 'guest' | 'e5b15b726e1224ca1d70ad9cf6a6e2a485de5478' |
| '47' | '2021-03-02 24:32:56.756966' | 'still ' | 'guest' | 'a7c3bdf1adc0e9f821f8727e83e76ae3821cf47e' |
| '48' | '2021-03-03 00:32:56.756966' | 'here '  | 'host'  | 'a7c3bdf1adc0e9f821f8727e83e76ae3821cf47e' |
+------+------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, i have two results for each guest_id, i'd like to have only the last one from the latest "created" resulting in:

```
+------+------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|  id  |           created            | message |  from   |                  guest_id                  |
+------+------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| '46' | '2021-03-02 23:32:56.756966' | 'bye'   | 'guest' | 'e5b15b726e1224ca1d70ad9cf6a6e2a485de5478' |
| '48' | '2021-03-03 00:32:56.756966' | 'here ' | 'host'  | 'a7c3bdf1adc0e9f821f8727e83e76ae3821cf47e' |
+------+------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

This is what i came up with:

```
queryaux    = Message.objects.filter(guest__reservation__home=home).values('guest_id').distinct().order_by()
queryset    = Message.objects.filter(guest__in=queryaux).latest('created')
```

**queryaux** contains the set of elements i need (no duplicates) but only the guest_id, not the full object (Because of values() )

**queryset** Should have the corresponding objects, but it gets only one object, the latest from the set

**My solution** (Which uses iterators and concatenation of querysets - probably not fast):

```
pseudo-code:

for elem in queryset: 
    final_queryset += Message.objects.filter(guest=elem).latest('created')
```

What are your suggestions to do this the right way?

Thank you.

EDIT:
For the sake of completion this is the message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    guest         = models.ForeignKey(Guest, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created       = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    message       = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    msgfrom       = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=MSGFROM)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to work with [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) here:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
>>> messages_ordered = Message.objects.filter(guest__id=OuterRef('id')).order_by('-created')
>>> for g in Guest.objects.values('id').annotate(latest_message_id=Subquery(messages_ordered.values('id')[:1])):
...     print(g['id'], g['latest_message_id'])
...
a7c3bdf1adc0e9f821f8727e83e76ae3821cf47e 48
e5b15b726e1224ca1d70ad9cf6a6e2a485de5478 46
```

`messages_ordered` gives you a `QuerySet` filtered by a guest and ordered by latest created date.

Then you can use the `messages_ordered` `QuerySet` as a subquery to annotate another `QuerySet` where you iterate over the guests with `Guest.objects.values('id')`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand the principle, but in the end, it does give me a list of ALL messages: https://pastebin.com/8hDqxNNL . Interesting enough, those IDs do not match the messages, but 45 is the latest message from that guest_id .

Comment: Ah, `guest` is a proper `ForeignKey` to another model, well that changes things! Then you need to iterate over the `Guest` model and annotate that `QuerySet`. Also then you don't need a `distinct()` as I'd expect your guests in `Guest` are unique. I modified the code, works for me when I run it on the changed models.

Comment: it wasn't quite that, because the fk is a string (token) i can still use it. 
With your help i reached the final goal : https://pastebin.com/9v0eu18R  . It works like a charm. Must say that i was close to rather use raw sql  at this point. AS you've assisted me to reach a solution, i'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 Message.objects.filter(guest__reservation__home=home).distinct('guest_id').order_by()
```

Comment: distinct('keyword')  won't work a database engine other than postgres, but thank you for your input Sergey